# jQuery: replace text inside link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="event tiny">
    <a href="/whatever">Something</a>
</div>
```

And I want to replace the `text` of this link with "Anything" …

When doing this …

`$('.event  a').replaceWith("Anything");`

… the text is replaced but also the link is gone.

When doing this …

`$('.event  a').text().replaceWith("Anything");`

… nothing happens.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this, if the new text is all the same.

```
$('.event a').text("Anything");
```

jQuery loops over the `a` elements, and replaces its content with the `"Anything"` text.

Answer (score 5):

These suggestions, for setting the inner text & URL link within a `a href` didn't work for me (using JQuery v1.8.3)

Here's what did work though:

**HTML**

```
 <a id="hrefAnalysisName" ></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("a#hrefAnalysisName").attr("href", "/SomePage/ShowAnalysisDetails.aspx");
$("a#hrefAnalysisName").text("Show analysis");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the link by `href` if it's related to the URL.

```
$('a[href="/whatever"]').text("Anything");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get this result the next ways result will be the same:

***HTML***

```
<div class="event tiny">
    <a class="html" href="/whatever">Something</a></br>
    <a class="text" href="/whatever">Something</a></br>
    <a class="replaceWith" href="/whatever">Something</a>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$('.event a.html').html('Anything-html')
$('.event a.text').text('Anything-text')
$('.event a.replaceWith').replaceWith('<a class="replaceWith" href="/whatever">Anything-replaceWith</a>')
```